# How to use hooks?

Tags: simics, dml-lang

I'm trying to understand how I can use hooks (https://github.com/intel/device-modeling-language/blob/main/doc/1.4/language.md#hook-declarations).

Is there a use-case or example that illustrates this?

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly the text could be even more clear about hooks have been added to support upcoming features. Today they serve only one feature: hook-bound after statements. However, this feature will be involved on more use cases by the time and the developers are aware of the need for examples.

Best regards / Simon

#IAmIntel